# Is it possible to know which php scripts are executed during an http request?

Tags: php

I am testing a php application which lately has been quite slow. So I have some questions:

1. How can I find where in the code, the application is consuming a lot of time?
2. Is there a way to know which php scripts are executed on an http request? (and how long each one takes?)

My question is beacuse there are a lot of php scripts and is quite hard to find out which ones are executed on each request.

Comment: http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Answer (score 0):

Use xdebug. PHPStorm or netbeans should support accepting incoming debug sessions.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUTolQw8K9A

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find out this information using Firebug in the firefox browser. http://getfirebug.com/

The net tab on Firebug allows you to view the specific requests as they are sent, the data in the request as well as the duration that the request takes to process.

I am sure other browsers have similar functionality.

Comment: This will only tell the OP what scripts are executing if they're being executed from the client. If the scripts are being included as part of a larger page then Firebug will not help.

Comment: Do you know a way to know wich scripts are being executed?, I mean, the index.php launch other scripts and such others lauch some others. Or the only way is to make a debug?